# How can I run Chrome continuously on an Ubuntu VPS server with Gnome GUI?

Tags: server, gnome, google-chrome

So I need Chrome to be running continuously on my Ubuntu VPS server, to make sure that it runs a particular extension that I have installed 24/7. How can I do this?

I have already installed Chrome, the GNOME GUI which I use, and the Chrome extension I want to have run.

What do I need to do to make it run without me?

Comment: Please edit your question and include more details and context about what exactly you are trying to run and the problems you are encountering. If you are already using a GUI, is there a reason you cannot simply launch the application?  What is the extension you need to run and what do you want it to do?

Comment: Hey @Nmath so I am launching Chrome and running it, but how do I keep it running after I close the GUI window? Does it just run by itself? (sorry, I'm really new to Ubuntu and VPS servers!)

Comment: I bought a VPS server with Ubuntu installed on it. I installed GNOME GUI, used it to login with a graphical interface, installed Chrome and my extension. My extension is a scraper. I want it to keep scraping. How do I make sure it keeps running when I turn my own PC (not the VPS) off?

I am trying to answer your question, I don't really understand what you're asking though.

Comment: How do I leave the application running? It's a custom-made extension that you search for something on Google, and then proceeds to navigate through SERP results to gather email addresses. It works fine on my Mac, problem is that it only works while I keep my Mac turned on. That's why I got a VPS, and moved it there.

Comment: You simply don't close the application

Comment: Ah, so if I don't turn off the VPS server, the applications I opened inside the GUI keep running by themselves even if close the VPS GUI window on my personal Mac? Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm just new to this :)

Comment: Yes, programs can't run when a device is off and software doesn't work when it's not running